# Why does this code throw an invalidAssignmentOperator error on the * and + operators?

Tags: java, function, lambda

Why does this code throw an invalidAssignmentOperator error on the * and + operators?

```
public static Function<Integer, Double> tariff = t -> {
    if (t = 500) {
        t * t;
    } else {
        t + t; 
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you mean  if(t==500) instead of if(t=500)?

Comment: Because `t * t;` is not a valid expression in Java if it's not being stored in a variable, passed as an argument, or returned to the caller. In this case, you should probably be returning it, since you're creating a `Function`. Also, `t = 500` assigns `t` to `500`, which is not a `boolean`, so your code won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using brackets `{}` requires the  `return` keyword
- Primtive type comparison is done with `==` and not `=`
- As you ask for `Double` as output you need to cast `(double)`, because `int*int > int` (same for `+`) **OR** use `Function<Integer, Integer>`

```
Function<Integer, Double> tariff = t -> {
    if(t==500) {
        return (double)t*t;
    } else {
        return (double)t+t;
    }
};
```

---

To simplify you could do :

```
Function<Integer, Double> tariff = t -> t==500 ? t*t : t+t;
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues with your code:

1. Equality check needs `==` : `t=500` should be `t==500`
2. When you have a complex code as lambda, the `return` statement is not implicit: so `t*t` does not return implicitly.
3. By multiplying/adding two integers you're trying to return a `integer` value while your expected return type is `double`, so compilation issues there.

Something like this would work:

```java
  public static Function<Integer, Integer> tariff = t -> {
    if (t == 500) {
      return t * t;
    } else {
      return t + t;
    }
  };
```

Implicit return would work for something like this:

```java
  public static Function<Integer, Integer> tariff = t -> (t == 500) ? t * t : t + t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function is throwing an invalidAssignmentOperator because you are not actually assigning `t*t` or `t+t` to anything.  You can try using `t*=t` and `t+=t` so that it will actually assign to `t`

Your method also is not returning anything and it should. An even better solution to my idea above would be to just return those values:

```
 public static Function<Integer, Double> tariff = t -> {
    if(t=500) {
        return t*t;
    } else {
        return t+t;
    }
};
```

Also, be sure to properly space out your code as shown by my code. It makes it much easier to read.